# increase line spacing within dmath environment

Tags: line-spacing

How do I increase line spacing in the dmath environment?

```
\begin{dmath}
{P(I_d)}={P(I_a}\\
{=P(I_b)}\\
{=P(I_c)}
\end{dmath}
```

The latex output gets cramped, the line spacing is much too narrow.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Hard to tell for sure without a full example, but you're using the breqn package? Have you tried something like `\setlength{\eqlinespacing}{20pt}`?

Comment: why use `dmath` with `\\ ` ? the whole point of `breqn` is that it does automatic line breaking not needing `\\ `

Comment: \setlength{\eqlinespacing}{20pt}  works!